# Fixing keg lid leaks

Tags: kegging

I have a few kegs with loose lids. That is, the lever doesn't offer a lot of resistance when you close the lid. I think the kegs are leaking CO2 from the lid. I have heard that putting pennies under the lever may help, but I had another idea. What if I bought a slightly thicker o-ring? Might this solve the leaky lid problem as well? I have a hard time getting the pennies to stay under the levers.

Comment: to find the leak, pressurize the keg and spray water on it. The bubbles will indicate where your problem is.

Answer (score 3):

The lever does not seal the lid. Sufficient pressure in the keg pushes the lid against the o-ring and against the top of the keg, sealing the lid; the lever just holds it all in place.

Add more CO₂ pressure.

Answer (score 0):

What @jsled said, but I want to add something else: Take your keg to your local homebrew shop that sells the same kegs that you have.

After testing where your leak is, ask to replace that one part (probably an o-ring) and test for leaks. Repeat until all the leaks are gone.

Remember to also test your tubing, disconnects and everything that is connected to the keg for leaks.